# Flowrouter.path not working

Tags: meteor, reactjs, flow-router

I am using flow router with react and meteor. Im trying to link an element using
`href={FlowRouter.path('ReadProjectMeta', {_id})}` and its not working
the console gives me this error

`router.js:347 There is no route for the path: /ReadProjectMeta`

yet ive defined the route this way

```
FlowRouter.route("/ReadProjectMeta/:_id", {
  action(params) {
    mount(ReadProjectMetaLayoutContainer, {
      components: (<ReadProjectMeta  _id={params._id}/>)
    }
  )
 }
});
```

this is how the component looks like

```
const ProjectList = ({project}) => ({ 
  project.map(({_id, projectheader,projectsummary,projectdescription}) => (
    <li key={_id}>
      <a href={FlowRouter.path('ReadProjectMeta', {_id})}>{projectheader}</a>
    </li>
  ))
})
```

what could be the problem . Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
  FlowRouter.route("/ReadProjectMeta/:_id", {
    name: 'project.meta'
    action(params) {
      mount(ReadProjectMetaLayoutContainer, {
        components: (<ReadProjectMeta  _id={params._id}/>)
      })
    }
  });

  FlowRouter.path('project.meta', {_id:response});
```

Comment: Im getting `response is not defined`

Comment: This works ` FlowRouter.path('project.meta', {_id);` thank you.